# How to port file system to Android?

Tags: android, filesystems, kernel, android-source

I have my own file system which was developed in Linux kernel. I want to find out if Android uses VFS also because my file system is built under VFS and uses VFS interfaces. If not, I need to identify what I need to change about my file system to fit into Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses a Linux kernel with some extensions and changes, but as far as I know, Android uses the file system part without changes. The default file system is for example [ext4](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2010/12/ext4-filesystem-hits-android-no-need-to-fear-data-loss.ars).

So your file system should work without much problems.

Comment: Thanks, dmeister. My file system is designed for memory device and uses buddy allocator to allocate block for file. I want to test it with large memory size, e.g. 4G~8G. Due to most Android device has very small RAM, and flash device is attached to flash controller which cannot be reached by buddy allocator, I have to try Android emulator. Do you know if I can change kernel in Android emulator to migrate my filesystem?